# Extract number of video or audio files from Wikipedia article

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to extract the number of videos or audio files present in a Wikipedia article, I searched the APIs but didn't find one for that.

I did notice that when using the API to extract the images for a specific page, the audio file with .ogg extension appears in the list with the images.

http://ar.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&page=%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%AB%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86&prop=images&redirects=

I don't know if this case can be generalized, and whether I can use it to count videos and audio files? Does anyone have another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all file types are treated equally by the API, but you can fetch the *mediatype* of each file, and use that to filter out the videos and audio files.

To get the mediatype of a file you would use [`prop=imageinfo`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties#imageinfo_.2F_ii) (this [will be changed](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/API_roadmap#Rewrite_prop.3Dimageinfo_from_scratch_as_prop.3Dfileinfo) to the more accurate `prop=fileinfo` in future versions) for each file. As `prop=images` can be used as a generator, you can get the list of files, and their mediatype, in one single API call, like **[this](https://ar.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=images&titles=%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%AB%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86&redirects=&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=mediatype&format=xml&continue=)**:

```
https://ar.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=images&titles=%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%AB%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86&redirects=&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=mediatype&continue=&format=xml
```

Here `images` is used as a generator, returning a list of files, and the list of files in its turn is being fed to the `imageinfo` call.

For each file, you will get something like this:

```
"2014232": {
  "pageid": 2014232,
  "ns": 6,
  "title": "\u0645\u0644\u0641:06-Salame-Al Aadm 001.ogg",
  "imagerepository": "local",
  "imageinfo": [
    {
      "mediatype": "AUDIO"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `mediatype` can be any of the following (copy-and-paste from the [manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MIME_type_detection)):

```
UNKNOWN     // unknown format
BITMAP      // some bitmap image or image source (like psd, etc). Can't scale up.
DRAWING     // some vector drawing (SVG, WMF, PS, ...) or image source (oo-draw, etc). Can scale up.
AUDIO       // simple audio file (ogg, mp3, wav, midi, whatever)
VIDEO       // simple video file (ogg, mpg, etc; no not include formats here that may contain executable sections or scripts!)
MULTIMEDIA  // Scriptable Multimedia (flash, advanced video container formats, etc)
OFFICE      // Office Documents, Spreadsheets (office formats possibly containing apples, scripts, etc)
TEXT        // Plain text (possibly containing program code or scripts)
EXECUTABLE  // binary executable
ARCHIVE     // archive file (zip, tar, etc)
```

The default mapping of mimetype <=> mediatype is available [here](https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fcore.git/master/includes%2Fmime.info), though it's possible to override this for an individual wiki.